SQL query to count blank data
I need a SQL query to count blank data as shown below; I want to count number of null for each regions. The code I use is giving only the null but not the total count of null values for each region
This is my SQL code:
select Region count(*) as Count 
from tablename 
where date is null 
group by region in ('77', 'LE');


I want the out put as Region and count. Please advise


What's the expected result if a (specified) has null dates only? Should it be returned with 0 count, or left out from the result?

You can explicitly pass the date is null to the count clause like this:
SELECT 
  Region,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Date IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS null_counts
FROM tablename
WHERE Region IN ("77", "le")
GROUP BY Region


it is not working and how to i define 77 and le region codes

Edited the code to include a where clause you can change region values inside parenthesis as needed.

unable to add table name it still gives error

added a from tablename clause. You can change the tablename with your actual table name.

Columns named 77 and le?

Use is null to select the data then group by the region.
select Region count(*) as Count 
from table_name 
where Date is null 
group by Region


The simpleset query is:
SELECT   region,  count(*) null_counts
FROM     tablename
WHERE    date IS NULL AND region IN ('77', 'le') 
GROUP BY region


Your are putting region condition in the wrong way , that way u will never get the count separately for each region. Remember the level of execution of an sql query. Here is the updated query
select Region count(*) as Count 
from tablename 
where date is null and region in ('77', 'LE')
group by region ;

